# Even you or you too?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, adjectives, forms-of-address

> A naked man was walking in a jungle. Seeing him, all the animals ran away.
>   The zebra asked the king lion: **you too/ even you?"** The lion replied," My friend, Keep the joke aside. That's a strange animal. The tail is in front. :)

I mean to say you run away despite being the king of the animals. Is using" Even you" correct in this context?

Answer (score 3):

Either one is correct, but I think "even you" definitely suits the joke better.  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/even) explains that *even* can be used adverbially "...as an intensive to stress an extreme or highly unlikely condition or instance", which is exactly what your joke is doing:  calling out the fact that the lion is running away, despite being the bravest, proudest creature in the jungle.

Answer (score 2):

"Even you" suggests that there is something remarkable about the lion running away when other animals have done so. Presumably that remarkable thing is the proverbial courage of lions.

If that is what you mean, there is nothing wrong with "even you".